# Runtime Error 1004 on one machine but not the other

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not so much familiar with macros, and can't figure out why I'm getting Runtime error 1004 on all other machines on the network but not on mine? I have created the file on my PC.
Here is the code:

```
Sub CustomerDetailed()
'
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = "Sales Customer Detailed Report"

    ShowSheets (sheetName)

    Sheets("SageWinman").Range("H2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Sales Customer Detailed Report").PivotTables("CustomerDetailed").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("Sales Customer Detailed Report").Select
End Sub
```

All it does - opens a hidden sheet on a click of a button then refreshes the pivot table data.
Debugger points out to this lane:

```
Sheets("SageWinman").Range("H2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out - why

You would have to setup **each user** with your own ODBC driver.
 - so, on network - make sure every user has ODBC driver pointing to ur DB and **setup on their machine**

Answer (score 0):

This error means usually some named range/cell does not exists.

So on the problematic line, this can be the Sheets("SageWinman") element if this sheet does not exist or Range("H2") if the cell naming param of your excel is set to numerical reference (instead of letters).

Check the reference style mode : tools / options / general / R1C1 reference style

Or to locate the error, replace the line with the following :

```
Sub CustomerDetailed()

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim thesheet as Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    sheetName = "Sales Customer Detailed Report"

    ShowSheets (sheetName)

    Set thesheet  = Sheets("SageWinman")
    Set r = thesheet .Range("H2")

    r.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Sales Customer Detailed Report").PivotTables("CustomerDetailed").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("Sales Customer Detailed Report").Select
End Sub
```

Re-run the script ; if it fails you should identify more precisly where.

Comment: `SageWinman` sheet does exist. As I mentioned - this macro runs fine on my machine, but not on others...

Comment: did you tried to split the line into several smaller parts in order to identify the precise source of error ?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes it gives an error on line: `r.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

Comment: what is your os and excel version ?

Comment: Did you checked the regional settings are the same ?